# Cannot set property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an add form where I am taking input location and others data.
In **service.ts** I have declared

```
export class SBOrderViewModel {
location: string;
agent: string;
}
```

In **add.component.ts**

```
sboVM: SBOrderViewModel;
this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      location: [],
      agent: [],
       });
```

whenever submit the data from frontend it will go to onSubmit() function in **add.componet.ts**

```
onSubmit() {

    this.sboVM.location = this.addForm.value.location;
    this.sboVM.agent = this.addForm.value.agent;
    this.sboService.Insert(this.sboVM).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/sborder/']);
      },
      this.errHandler.bind(this)
    );
  }
```

In add.componet.html

```
 <form #addorder [formGroup]="addForm" clrForm clrLayout="horizontal">
            <clr-input-container>
            <label>Location</label>
            <input class="txtboxwidth" formControlName="location" clrInput type="text" name="location"/>
          </clr-input-container>
    <button class="mrgnlft btn btn-success" [disabled]='addForm.invalid' *ngIf="btnvisibility" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Save</button>
     </form>
```

I can't figure out why it shows Cannot set property 'location' of undefined when I add the value in addform and submit. Your kind help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Seems like **this.sboVM** is null in onSubmit function.
[image]

bcs other that ur code is working

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.yes this.sboVM was null. after declaring inside constructor this.sboVM = new SBOrderViewModel() it resolved . but when I submit the form it shows  Cannot read property 'control' of null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the variable this.sboVM

In the constructor add: `this.sboVM = new SBOrderViewModel();`

Comment: @Ale_Binaco thanks for your kind response. I have added in the constructor 
this.sboVM = new SBOrderViewModel();
but now it shows Cannot read property 'control' of null when I submit the form

Comment: @Mahmud You can wrap the form by checking if it is null <div *ngIf="addForm"></div>

Comment: @Ale_Binaco when I request the /api/sborder/insert it http response 400 error and shows the jason value could not be converted to system.int 32 . PAth : $orderId

Comment: @Mahmud I think could be an api deserialization problem. If you are using ASP.NET Core 3.0 the default package is System.Text.Json. You can use Newtonsoft (install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson and in the startup  services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();)

Answer (score 0):

You can check by updating below code in add.component.ts

```
this.addForm = new FormGroup({
      location: new FormControl(null, [])
      agent: new FormControl(null, [])
     });
```